# Printf no muestra el contenido de las variables

Tags: php, poo

tengo un problema con la función printf cuando intento pintar en pantalla el contenido de las variables de session me arroja un mensaje de undefined $_SESSION, pero si uso print_r o le hago un var_dump si que me imprime el contenido de dichas variables, por eso acudo a ustedes para que me ayuden a entender que pasa, les dejo el codigo:

PHP CONTROLLER

```
<?php 
class Router{
    public $route;

    public function __construct($route){
        $session_options = array(
            'use_only_cookies' => 1,
            'auto_start' => 1,
            'read_and_close' => true
        );

        if( !isset($_SESSION) ) session_start($session_options);

        if( !isset($_SESSION['ok']) ) $_SESSION['ok'] = false;

        if($_SESSION['ok']){
            //Aqui va toda la programacion de nustra webapp
            $this->route = isset($_GET['r']) ? $_GET['r'] : 'home';

            $controller = new ViewController();

            switch ($this->route) {
                case 'home':
                    $controller->load_view('home');
                    break;

                case 'movieseries':
                    $controller->load_view('movieseries');
                    break;

                case 'usuarios':
                    $controller->load_view('users');
                    break;

                case 'status':
                    $controller->load_view('status');
                    break;

                case 'salir':
                    $user_session = new SessionController();
                    $user_session->logout();
                    break;

                default:
                    $controller->load_view('error404');
                    break;
            }

        }else{
            if( !isset($_POST['user']) && !isset($_POST['pass']) ){
                //mostrar un formulario de autenticacion
                $login_form = new ViewController();
                $login_form->load_view('login');
            }else{
                $user_session = new SessionController();
                $session = $user_session->login($_POST['user'], $_POST['pass']);

                if( empty($session) ){
                    $login_form = new ViewController();
                    $login_form->load_view('login');
                    header('Location: ./?error=El usuario ' . $_POST['user'] . ' y el password proporcionado no coinciden');
                }else{
                    $_SESSION['ok'] = true;

                    foreach ($session as $row) {
                        $_SESSION['user'] = $row['user'];
                        $_SESSION['email'] = $row['email'];
                        $_SESSION['name'] = $row['name'];
                        $_SESSION['birthday'] = $row['birthday'];
                        $_SESSION['pass'] = $row['pass'];
                        $_SESSION['role'] = $row['role'];
                    }

                    header('Location: ./');
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public function __destruct(){
        unset($this);
    }
}
```

PHP VIEW

```
<?php
$template = '
<article class="item">
    <h2 class="p1">Hola %s, bienvenid@ a Freeflix</h2>
    <h3 class="p1">Tus peliculas y series favoritas</h3>
    <p class="p1 f1_25">Tu nombre es <b>%s</b></p>
    <p class="p1 f1_25">Tu email es <b>%s</b></p>
    <p class="p1 f1_25">Tu cumpleaños es <b>%s</b></p>
    <p class="p1 f1_25">Tu perfil de usuario tiene un nivel de <b>%s</b></p>
</article>  
';

printf(
    $template, 
    $_SESSSION['user'],
    $_SESSSION['name'],
    $_SESSSION['email'],
    $_SESSSION['birthday'],
    $_SESSSION['role']
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Notaste que en el printf estas usando $_SESSSION con 3 'S'?

Comment: jajaja por dios, pero que tonto soy, gracias por el dato ese era el problema. Por favor que un mod cierre esta pregunta.

Comment: jajaja nos pasa a todos :)
Me alegra haber ayudado